# Separate each rom listview android

Tags: android, listview

I want to build some apps with ListView to look like this :

[image]

But what I've succeded to build is like this :

[image]

Is there any possibilities to separate each row like picture 1 ?

Comment: Which language/UI? What is your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best thing you could do is give the background of each `ListViewItem` rounded corners with [shape](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) and just remove the divider by doing

```
android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
```

To get the same height I think you can play around in shape itself. Don't forget to make the `ListView` itself transparent.

Answer (score 2):

Change the divider color to `transparent` by `android:divider="@android:color/transparent"`
And increase the divider height by `android:dividerHeight property` with  will help you increase the space between ListView items

```
<ListView 
  ...
  android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
  android:dividerHeight="10.0dp"/>
```

Comment: why downvote my answer? correct me if i'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late But you can use `CardView` hear as your list item.

**list_item.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/cvItem"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:clickable="true"
     app:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
     app:cardUseCompatPadding="true" >

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivCover"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/b1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="ZXCZX"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            <!-- more customization --> />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and as per @Phan Văn Linh's suggestion you can give. but `android:dividerHeight` will be `0dp`

```
<ListView 
    ...
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

On way to achieve this is by setting custom Layout for list by setting  margin Left and right and and using your background as the colour. For top and down between ListView now change the colour of list divider and change the length of divider where us add your ListView

```
            android:divider="#898989"
            android:dividerHeight="5dp"
```